# Retrieve membership information of a GitHub user

Tags: github, github-api

I try to retrieve the membership details of a GitHub user using the GitHub API and the endpoint `/user/memberships/orgs`.

I'm member of multiple organizations but all I get as a response is:

```
200 OK
[]
```

So there's no membership information shown for my user. I have an access token with scope `user`. Did I miss something? I also can't find any information regarding this in the official API documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#list-your-organization-memberships

Comment: First try to hit `https://api.github.com/user` and see if you are indeed getting the correct user or not. The token has to be of the user for which you are pulling this. The return data of `/user` can confirm if the user being checked is correct or not. Also sometimes I have seen that in some cases there is some kind IP abuse protection from github which alters the data returned, so I will also check the same thing through a different network if posisble

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get information about an organization membership the OAuth app has to be trusted by each company the user has a membership. If it's not a trusted OAuth app you don't get any information about a membership of the user for this organization.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/authorizing-oauth-apps/#oauth-apps-and-organizations